# Android Management API: Failed to patch policy - Caller is not authorized to manage enterprise

Tags: android-management-api, android-enterprise

I have been working with the Android Management API to try and manage the policy of my company's existing enterprise. My company account has the Owner role within the organization and the roles Owner and Service Account Admin for the service account mentioned later.

I followed the [Quickstart Guide](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb) to get familiar with the API and made some modifications for a more permanent solution along the way such as creating a service account with the Android Management User role via the Google Cloud Platform and generating a JSON key to acquire credentials rather than going through the OAuth2 flow like in the guide. This allowed me to authenticate properly, but when it comes time to patch the policy as such,

```
androidmanagement.enterprises().policies().patch(
    name=policy_name,
    body=policy_json
).execute()
```

I get the following error:

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/XXXXXXXXX/policies/<policy_name>?alt=json returned "Caller is not authorized to manage enterprise.". Details: "Caller is not authorized to manage enterprise.">
```

I have verified that the service account I am authenticating with has the Android Management User role, and thus has the androidmanagement.enterprises.manage permission.

I have also attempted to make this call with an elevated admin role in the organization.

Is there a chance that I need to have created the enterprise with my own account to manage the enterprise? The guide suggests that an organization can create multiple enterprises. In which case, would I need to create a new Google account not associated with my organization's enterprise and create a new enterprise that way?

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to use your own google account to call Android Management API since your organization account may not be compatible with the quickstart.

To access the Android Management API your service account requires the androidmanagement.enterprises.manage permission, which can be granted by the **Android Management User** role (or roles/androidmanagement.user). Kindly check this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/service-account) for details regarding creating a service account.

Please keep in mind that the enterprise you created as part of the colab instructions can only be managed using the colab itself. To allow your cloud project to manage an organization, you will need to create one using the client configuration from your cloud project.